# How can I achieve this type of glass and ocean results?

Tags: shaders, glass

I want this type of result of glass for my scenes but I am not able to achieve it. Can anyone tell me how these materials are being applied on the objects and what shaders are being used?

[image]

Comment: and what did you try so far...?

Comment: i turned the roughness down to 0.1 made the transmission to 1.also change the blend mode to aphla blend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made something pretty similar to what you show, that is a mix between *Diffuse, Transparent, Glossy* and *Glass*. You can probably get rid of *Diffuse*:

[image]

As for the glass you need to push the *Transmission* value up to 1, lower down the *Roughness* value, in the material *Settings* choose *Blend Mode > Alpha Blend* and *Screen Space Refraction*, and in the *Render* panel enable *Screen Space Reflections* and *Refraction*:

[image]

In Eevee though you'll have problem to see transparency through transparency so the part of the bottle that will be under water must not be transparent. What you can do is create a second bottle at the exact same place, give it an opaque material, and a *Boolean* modifier, *Intersect* type and with the sea as boolean *Object* so that only the part under water is visible:

[image]

Comment: But what about glass bottle please help me with it..

Comment: I've edited my answer, I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @moonboots for such a great help.☺️☺️